# How to style a CSS submenu?

Tags: html, css, menu, nav, submenu

I was trying to follow [this example](http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/css-menu/demo/index.html) but I cannot make it work for my needs, some help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Ok, my submenu is better positioned thanks to yourkishore and I solved a little how to handle nested menus now, but my submenu is still appearing right in the bottom of my text?

[** Updated jsFiddle **](http://jsfiddle.net/fquH6/4/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="menubar">
    <div id="title">title</div>
    <li>File
        <ul>
        <li>Photoshop CC</li>
        <li>Illustrator CC Adobe</li>
        <li>My Web Design
            <ul>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Config</li>
</ul>
<div id=other></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {height:100%;width:100%;margin:0;}
#menubar {
    background: #eeeeee;
    height:25%;
    list-style-type: none;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-table;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:99;
}
#menubar #title {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 5%;
    font-size:140%;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#menubar li {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0 1%;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#menubar li:hover {
    background-color:#7faddb;
}
#menubar li > ul {
    background-color:white;
    z-index:99;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#menubar li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#other {
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is showing inside the menu because, they are inside. To make them appear outside when you mouse over. you need to set a property called position.

for #menubar li you need to add poistion:relative

and then for #menubar li ul you need to add postion:absolute.

Menus always work on this important property. Without this there is no menu with nested list. Just learn css positionings. All the best.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that solved a few things but I still have a mess.

Comment: Send me messages, if you dont understand anything in the future regarding web development.

Answer (score 0):

It works Fine in your fiddle,use this HTML

```
<div id="title">title</div>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>File
        <ul>
        <li>Photoshop CC</li>
        <li>Illustrator CC Adobe</li>
        <li>My Web Design
            <ul>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Config</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div id=other></div>
```

and use this CSS

```
 body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

body {

    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px;
}

nav {

    text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }


nav ul {
    padding: 0 20px;

    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    padding:12px;
    }
        nav ul li:hover {
            background: #505050;

        }
            nav ul li:hover a {
                color: #171717;
            }

        nav ul li a {
            display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
            color: #994411; text-decoration: none;
        }


    nav ul ul {
        background: #888888; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
        position: absolute; top: 100%;
    }
        nav ul ul li {
            float: none; 
            border-top: 1px solid #111;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; position: relative;
        }
            nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 1px 40px;
                color: #666;
            }   
                nav ul ul li a:hover {
                    background: #333;
                }

    nav ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
    }
        #other {
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that can fit to my menu bar. I'm still very new at this :)

Comment: changed the HTML and css as per your menubar.try it.